# .filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter, functional-programming

This is my object (made sure it's a typeof object):

```
{
    "1": {"user_id":1,"test":"","user_name":"potato0","isok":"true"},

    "2":{"user_id":2,"test":"","user_name":"potato1","isok":" true"},

    "3":{"user_id":3,"test":"","user_name":"potato2","isok":" true"},

    "4":{"user_id":4,"test":"","user_name":"potato3","isok":"locationd"}

}
```

Why using `.filter` doesn't work for me?

Is it because my variable is `typeof object` and the method works only with arrays?

```
this.activeUsers = window.users.filter( function(user) {
     // return ( (user.test === '0') && (user.isok === '0') ); 
     return user.user_id === 1;
});
```

getting the error:

> .filter is not a function

What is the suggested alternative with objects?

Comment: `filter` works on arrays. Your's isn't an array. When in doubt, always refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: what is the suggested solution to filter objects? @31piy

Comment: @wellhellothere fix whatever is giving you an object instead of an array.

Comment: I think this is a good Question. Just add a comment that Array.prototype.filter works only of array and therefore you must use some Object.values() or Object.keys() to work with..

Comment: @KevinB Can you please help me with your suggestion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512730/is-it-possible-to-return-json-encode-but-as-an-array-and-not-an-object-so-i-c

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method on arrays. Since the code you posted contains an object, you're seeing this error. You may want to apply filter after getting all the values from the object using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), like this:

```js
var users = {
  "1": {
    "user_id": 1,
    "test": "",
    "user_name": "potato0",
    "isok": "true"
  },

  "2": {
    "user_id": 2,
    "test": "",
    "user_name": "potato1",
    "isok": " true"
  },

  "3": {
    "user_id": 3,
    "test": "",
    "user_name": "potato2",
    "isok": " true"
  },

  "4": {
    "user_id": 4,
    "test": "",
    "user_name": "potato3",
    "isok": "locationd"
  }
};

console.log(Object.values(users).filter(user => user.user_id === 1));
```

Comment: I'll approve your answer (4 min limit). Is this slower than running the same on an array (in terms of performance).

Comment: @wellhellothere -- it is of course slower since we're first extracting the object's values, and then iterating over those. If you can fix the origin of this code so that it gives you an array instead, that's the recommended fix for it.

Comment: If you can review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512730/is-it-possible-to-return-json-encode-but-as-an-array-and-not-an-object-so-i-c

Comment: @wellhellothere -- sorry, I don't know php.