# Is it possible to return json_encode() but as an array and not an object, so I can use `.filter()` or `.forEach()` methods easily

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6

I just want to make sure there is no such thing... because I cannot find anything mentioning this:

Currently, when I use `json_encode($array)`, I get a **json object** that look like this:

```
{
    "1": {"user_id":1,"test":"","user_name":"potato0","isok":"true"},

    "2":{"user_id":2,"test":"","user_name":"potato1","isok":" true"},

    "3":{"user_id":3,"test":"","user_name":"potato2","isok":" true"},

    "4":{"user_id":4,"test":"","user_name":"potato3","isok":"locationd"}
}
```

and I would like to run the `.filter()`/`.forEach()` methods.

but they wont run on objects (`{...}`) and will run on arrays (`[...]`).

Edit: It seems that it's not sure what I am getting so this is a real var_dump and json_encode() example:

> var_dump($array);

```
array (size=2)
  'status' => boolean true
  'data' => 
    array (size=3)
      'fruits' => 
        array (size=9)
          'fruit_id' => int 246
          'fruit_name' => string 'banana' (length=15)
      'vegtables' => 
        array (size=9)
          'veg_id' => int 253
          'fruit_name' => string 'potato' (length=20)
```

> echo json_encode(['status' => true, 'data' => $fruits]);

```
{  
   "status":true,
   "data":{  
      "fruits":{  
         "fruit_id":246,
         "fruit_name":"banana"
      },
      "vegtables":{  
         "veg_id":253,
         "veg_name":"potato"
      }
   }
}
```

the json returned is defined as an "Object" (checked using `typeof`)

** I'm not willing to turn my object to an array on the js side, I aware about this "trick" and I prefer to fetch a json array from php as an array, please focus on my question **

Comment: Your `$array` looks to be *1-indexed*, not *0-indexed*, don't know PHP, but that doesn't look promising

Comment: `Object.values(.....)`

Comment: @Snow Can you please explain more briefly?

Comment: Plz add the php script

Comment: @PranavCBalan your solution is something I'm trying to prevent actually. I do not want to turn the object to an array every time I need to do something with it (to avoid extra processes).

Comment: @wellhellothere :  then you have to create an array instead of an object

Comment: @wellhellothere your idea seems a little vague but straight forward if we speak about it you want to perform array operations on the values of an object so why do you think it is 'extra processes' to make it array before operating with array methods?

Comment: you can still use `for (var key in yourObj) { console.log(yourObj[key]); }`

Comment: @PranavCBalan that's exactly what i'm asking, how do i get json_encode to send my an array.

Comment: in `php` you are creating object inside object

Comment: @wellhellothere  : share the code which generates it

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the main object to an Array. I think below code is what you're looking for.

Your Input :

```
 var data = {
    "1": {"user_id":1,"test":"","user_name":"potato0","isok":"true"},

    "2":{"user_id":2,"test":"","user_name":"potato1","isok":" true"},

    "3":{"user_id":3,"test":"","user_name":"potato2","isok":" true"},

    "4":{"user_id":4,"test":"","user_name":"potato3","isok":"locationd"}
};
```

Convert Object to Array

```
 var result = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
  return data[key];
});
```

Now you can use Filter for the converted array

```
var filtered = result.filter(row => { return row.user_id > 1; });
```

And Filtered Result is:

```
[{
"user_id": 2,
"test": "",
"user_name": "potato1",
"isok": " true"
},{
"user_id": 3,
"test": "",
"user_name": "potato2",
"isok": " true"
},{
"user_id": 4,
"test": "",
"user_name": "potato3",
"isok": "locationd"
}]
```

Hope this is what you're looking for and here is working demo link : https://playcode.io/282703?tabs=console&script.js&output